# Join table variable vs join view

Tags: t-sql, join, view

I have a stored procedure which is running quite slow. Therefore I want to extract some of the query in a separate view.

My code looks something like this:

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE(..)

INSERT INTO @tmpTable (..) *query* (returns 3000 rows)

Select ... from table1
inner join table2
inner join table3
inner join @tmpTable
...
```

I then extract (copy-paste) the *query* and put it in a view - i.e. vView.

Doing this will then give me a different result:

```
Select ... from table1
    inner join table2
    inner join table3
    inner join vView
    ...
```

Why? I can see that the vView and the @tmpTable both returns 3000 rows, so they should match (also did a except query to check).

Any comments would be much appriciated as I feel quite stuck with this..

EDITED:

This is the full query for getting the result (using @tmpTable or vView gives me different results, although the appear the same):

```
select dep.sid as depsid, dep.[name], COUNT(b.sid) as possiblelogins, count(ls.clientsid) as logins
from department dep
inner join relationship r on dep.sid=r.primarysid and r.relationshiptypeid=27 and r.validto is null
inner join [user] u on r.secondarysid=u.sid
inner join relationship r2 on u.sid=r2.secondarysid and r2.validto is null and r2.relationshiptypeid in (1,37)
inner join client c on r2.primarysid=c.sid
inner join ***@tmpTable or vView*** b on b.sid = c.sid
left outer join (select distinct clientsid from logonstatistics) as ls on b.sid=ls.clientsid
GROUP BY dep.sid, dep.[name],dep.isdepartment
HAVING dep.isdepartment=1
```

Comment: Can you give more code and information please? Is there a WHERE on the @tmpTable query? Is the JOIN different? Is it "more rows" or "duplilcates"?

Comment: Ive added the select itself, but the query for building @tmpTable and vView is a heavy one which contains both inner joins, union etc, but the result set is distinct.

Comment: And the INSERT INTO @tmpTable code with definition please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe don't need the view/table if you change to this.

It joins on to `client c` and appears to be there only to JOIN onto `logonstatistics`

```
--remove inner join ***@tmpTable or vView*** b on b.sid = c.sid
--change JOIN
left outer join (select distinct clientsid from logonstatistics) as ls on c.sid=ls.clientsid
```

And change `COUNT(b.sid)` to `COUNT(c.sid)` in the SELECT clause

Otherwise, if you get different results you have two options I can see:

1. Table and view have different data. Have you run a line by line comparsion?
2. One has NULL, one has a value (especially for the sid column which will affect the JOIN)

Finally, when you says "different results" do you mean you get x2 or x3 rows? A different COUNT? What?

Comment: An INNER JOIN can also be used for filtering rows.